# Blank html Page to Android HTTP Post Request before the result

Tags: php, android, html, authentication, filter

I just copy the whole thing from this website:

http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/#comment-1236

I try to send a HTTP post request with username and password to a PHP script, supposingly it should return either 1 or 0 in an echo.

But when I check the response, it returns a blank html page before 1 or 0

```
<i><.!DOCTYPE html><Br></i>
<.html lang="en"><Br>
<.head><Br>
    <.meta charset="utf-8" /><Br>
    <.title><./title><Br>
<./head><Br>
<.body>     <./body><Br>
<./html><Br>
0
```

Could some please tell how can I solve it?

Comment: If you are working with authentication, using an integer return value when you are expecting back an entire page is a bad idea. I would suggest having your php script set the HTTP code to 401 (forbidden) if not auth, and return a normal 200 on success. EDIT: Just looked at the code, I would also suggest sanitizing your input.

Comment: In fact, I'm tryong to remove 
<.!DOCTYPE html>
<.html lang="en">
<.head>
<.meta charset="utf-8" />
<.title><./title>
<./head>
<.body> <./body>
<./html>

but don't know how